# Рекурсия вложенных объектов JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, выводит свойства объектов с определенным форматированием, но выводит только до 2 уровня. Нужно как-то прикрутить рекурсию..

```
function showObject(obj) {
    let mes = "";

    for(let key in obj ) {
        
        if (typeof obj[key] == "string") {
            mes = key + " - " + "'" + obj[key] + "'";
        } else {
            mes = key + " - " + obj[key];
        }
        
        if(typeof obj[key] == "object") {
            
            for(let keyProp in obj[key]) {
                mes = key + "-" + keyProp + " - " + "'" + obj[key][keyProp] + "'";
                console.log(mes)
            }
        } else {
          console.log(mes)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А в чём сложности? Что такое рекурсия вы знаете.

Comment: Только учусь, но понимаю как это работает. В данном случае когда я пытаюсь прикрутить рекурсию у меня либо переполняется память либо выводится не в таком формате как я хочу нужно что бы было dates-graduationFromUniversity -Part1-  каждое свойство после - добавляет уровень объекта, не могу понять где ошибка.

Comment: Напишите свой код и все проблемы которые с ним возникают. А также пример самого исходного  объекта.

Comment: Ссылка на код - https://codepen.io/huper12345/pen/dyewPzB . Проблема такая, что когда пытаюсь сделать рекурсию что бы все так же работало.

Comment: суть рекурсии - к каждому из внутренних элементов применять эту же функцию. ты делаешь одни и те же действия: перебираешь свойство объект и добавляешь `-`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вот так. Сделал через рекурсию: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azamat96/xgvrhfbd/1/)

```
function showObject(obj, prefix = '') {
    for(let key in obj ) {

        const arrow = prefix.length > 0 ? prefix + '->' : ''

        if (typeof obj[key] === "object" && obj[key] !== null) {
            return showObject(obj[key], arrow + key)
        } 

        // не учитываю массив
        let mes = arrow + key + " - " + obj[key];
        console.log(mes)
    }
}

showObject(obj1);
```